# Laravel 4 - trying to use 'create' layout with and without default content in the form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have create.blade.php view modal and i want it to be used with and without default content.

example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::text('title', $content->title, array('class' => 'form-control' , 'placeholder' => 'Insert Title Here.')) }}
</div>
```

The $content obj doesn't always exists so i get error like this (when there is no content set to $content):

> Trying to get property of non-object

This is my controller function:

```
public function create($default_content = '')
{
    return View::make('content.create')
        ->with('content', $default_content);
}
```

I tried to set default/fake obj:

> $default_content = ($default_content == '') ? new stdClass() :
>   $default_content;

But in the end i get error that $content->title dose not exists.
Should i set all the variables to NULL in the obj if $default_content is empty ? if so, how?

There must be a better way to handle this problem - Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you could probably do.

I'm assuming since you are building a form, `content` is actually a model, in which case when you open the form, use `Form::model($content)`, then Laravel will automatically set those values for you.

You can read more about that here... http://laravel.com/docs/html#form-model-binding

If `content` is not a model, you could setup a view composer, which will automatically inject `$content` into your view each time it's loaded.

```
View::composer('content', function($view)
{
    // Retrieve your content

    // Inject the content into the view each time it's loaded.
    $view->with('content', $content);
});
```

Can check http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers for more info

The last solution would be to check for it in your view before setting it though usually, it's a good idea to keep this kind of logic out of your views.

```
{{ Form::text('title', isset($content->title) ? $content->title : '', array('class' => 'form-control' , 'placeholder' => 'Insert Title Here.')) }}
```

Comment: First method seems to work very good! but i am forced to put "null" in the value of the Form::text otherwise i get error (if i try to put array with classes) - i am doing it right by placing "null" in the value? Thanks!